# Logical operators issue

Tags: php, logical-operators

Given the below variables:

```
$field1;
$field2;
$field3;
$field4;
$field5;
```

How can I use logical operators so that the user has to fill in either field: 1,2,3 OR either field 1, 2, 4, 5. If user does not do one of the following, then I want to give error required fields not complete.

I have tried:

```
if ((!$field1 | !$field2 |!$field3) | (!$field1 | !$field2 |!$field4|!$field5)) 
    $errors[] = 'You did not complete all of the required fields.';
```

Comment: the `|` operator is a [bitwise OR](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)—not what you want. Use `||` for logical OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!
  // Exactly 1,2,3 are filled in (not 4, 5)
  (!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && !empty($field3) && empty($field4) && empty($field5))
  // or Exactly 1,2,4,5 are filled in (not 3)
  && !(!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && !empty($field4) && !empty($field5) && empty($field3))
) {
   // print error
}
```

Comment: does this also make it so that if the user fills in just field 1 for example, it'll give an error?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, that was my understanding of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && !empty($field3)) {
    //process
} else if (!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && !empty($field4) && !empty($field5)) {
    //process
} else {
    $errors[] = 'You did not complete all of the required fields.';
}
```

---

Or, require that no extra fields are filled in for a given option:

```
if (!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && !empty($field3) &&
    empty($field4) && empty($field5)) {
    //process
} else if (!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && !empty($field4) && !empty($field5) &&
     empty($field3)) {
    //process
} else {
    $errors[] = 'You did not complete all of the required fields.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `a = not empty $field1, b = not empty $field2, ..., e = not empty $field5`

You want

```
(a && b && c) || (a && b && d && e)
= (a && b) && ( c || (d && e))
```

In php:

```
if(!empty($field1) && !empty($field2) && 
   ( !empty($field3) || (!empty($field4) && !empty($field5)) 
) {
   // process
} else {
   // error
}
```

If you consider 0 as a valid value use `isset` in place of `empty`.

Finally get to use those algebra I learned in school.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure where the `$fields` are comming from, but the following might do the trick:

```
if (!(isset($field1) && isset($field2) && isset($field3)) || !(isset($field1) && isset($field2) && isset($field3) && isset($field4)){
   //Set the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally do something like the following for simple validations such as this

```
$fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5');

foreach($fields as $field) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$field]) || strlen(trim($_POST[$field])) == 0) {
        // set error message
    }
}
```